# fetch larger images from Facebook with Koala using the get_connection method

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

The [documentation of the Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API#getting-public-data) gives an example how to fetch posts from Facebook, including a picture.

```
client = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
client.get_connection('someuser', 'posts',
                {limit: @options[:max_items],
                  fields: ['message', 'id', 'from', 'type',
                            'picture', 'link', 'created_time', 'updated_time'
                    ]})
```

Below this example the documentation makes a note:

> You can pass a ‘type’ hash key with a value of ‘small’, ‘normal’, ‘large’, or ‘square’ to obtain different picture sizes, with the default being ‘square’. Also, you may need the user_photos permission.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work:

```
client.get_connection("officialstackoverflow", "posts", 
     {limit: 5, type: "large", fields: [:picture, :message, :type]})
```

Unfortunately, I get the same picture as I would get when omitting the type param. How do I have to pass the type hash correctly?